# How to add data on keplergl React from database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, kepler.gl

I'm working with keplergl and I'd like to retrieve data from my database but kepler can't detect my data despite receiving an object in my console.

[Receiving my object in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaaLr.png)

What should I do?
thank you in advance

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  keplerGl: keplerGlReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(taskMiddleware));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes />
      <Map />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Fetch + json + map

```
function Map() {

  
  
  console.log("data", data)
```

configure parameters

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      dispatch(
        addDataToMap({
          datasets: {
            info: {
              label: "COVID-19",
              id: "covid19"
            },
            data:data
          },
          option: {
            centerMap: true,
            readOnly: false
          },
          config: {

          }
        })
      );
    }
  }, [dispatch, data]);
```

KeplerGl Component

```
  return (
    
    <KeplerGl
      id="covid"
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_API}
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
    />
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find a tutorial on how to dynamically update a dataset with new data here: http://vis.academy/#/kepler.gl/3-load-config

please see section "2. Replace an existing dataset with new data with the same format , keeping the current config."